# Join unicode u with non-ASCII value in python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string variable -

```
val = "Rë█_Rajkumar"
```

Now I would like to prefix this value with unicode like-

```
unicode = u"Rë█_Rajkumar"
```

But when I try using join -

```
nor = u''.join(val)
```

it throws the exception-

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried different ways but couldn't make this work, how should I join

Comment: Have you looked at any of the many other `UnicodeDecodeError` questions here and elsewhere? The [Python how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix only works for *literal values*; the syntax with prefix creates a different object type from the syntax without.

To convert *already created `str` objects*, you need to decode them to Unicode, and in the other direction `unicode` objects can be converted to `str` objects by encoding them to bytes.

If you don't explicitly decode bytes to Unicode, Python does this for you, implicitly, with the ASCII codec. That failed for you, so you want to do it explicitly. You don't want to use `u''.join()` for this; that's for concatenating sequences. Use the `str.decode()` method here:

```
nor = val.decode('utf8')
```

What codec you use to decode with depends on your data. I've assumed here that your data is encoded with UTF-8. You'll have to determine for yourself what the correct codec is for your data.

You probably want to do some reading on Unicode vs. byte strings here:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder